# Tiger: `rtm` is listening on socket XXXX

Tags: security, cron, log, sockets

On my Ubuntu serve 12.04 LTS, Tiger is reporting a lot of stuffs like this:

```
OLD: --WARN-- [lin002i] The process `rtm' is listening on socket 60404 (UDP) on every interface.
NEW: --WARN-- [lin002i] The process `rtm' is listening on socket 60007 (UDP) on every interface.
```

What is `rtm`? Why does it need to open ports? Is it safe to block it? If so, How can I do that, since I cannot know which port will be used in advance…